# Preload attribute on HTML5 video on AngularJS directive not working

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I am using an AngularJS directive to load a video element on an AngularJS app. The directive is as follows:

```
app.directive("aVideo", function($http){
    return {
        template: '<video class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" ng-src="[[[post.creative.media.mediaUri]]]" poster="[[[post.creative.posterUri]]]" controls crossorigin="anonymous" preload="none"</video>',
        transclude: true,
        scope:{
            post: "=",
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {         
            $(element).find("video").on("play", function () {
                $http.post('/post/' + scope.post.creative.cuid + '/views?_csrf=' + csrfToken)
                .success(function(data){

                })
                .error(function(error){             

                }); 
            });                     
        },
    }
});
```

Pay special attention to the template attribute on the directive. When the browser renders the page, the following is the html output:

```
<video class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" ng-src="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/creatives/6f728304eecc6a4348b87a2be0de0f954cd3.mp4" poster="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/creatives/e231b9d1-0df8-4a9f-81fd-70ad676d5698" controls="" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="none" < video src="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/creatives/6f728304eecc6a4348b87a2be0de0f954cd3.mp4"></video>
```

First, there is an unexpected "< video" inserted by angular into the video element. Second, you can see there is an 'ng-src' and a 'src' attribute both in the html returned to the browser. Lastly, the 'preload' attribute is not being respected, as the network traces show me that all the video elements generated on the page via this directive (3 in total) pre-load completely in parallel.

So I am looking for guidance on how to properly setup an AngularJS directive to display video elements. I am particularly looking for the 'preload' attribute to be respected, as pre-loading all video elements consumes too much bandwidth on the client.

Comment: You don't have the closing `>` in your template. If this is the only issue with you question, I suggest you delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your template. The `>` end of the opening tag is not there. Could that be it, especially that `preload` is the last attribute?

BTW, the `ng-` attributes don't get cleaned up by Angular, so, their presence in the generated HTML is normal.

**Update:**

According to [this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/), you can't rely on `preload` attribute to enforce preload behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, there was a typo on the directive template. So easy to oversee such a simple problem, it is always good to have a second pair of eyes looking at your code! However, the preload attribute is still ignored, even though the html code for the video element is now correct. It might not be an angularjs problem anymore, but still, all video elements loaded are being loaded completely despite the presence of preload=none

Comment: So, the attribute shows in the HTML now, but with no effect?

Comment: that is correct. The actual html tag is:
<video class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" ng-src="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/creatives/4a0c300f00183549d208d9fc1bf28be34522.m4v" poster="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/creatives/e768952e-1a73-478a-a762-a074a9ba115f" controls="controls" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="none" src="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/creatives/4a0c300f00183549d208d9fc1bf28be34522.m4v"></video>

All video elements are loaded to their entirety. This is on Chrome on Windows. IE 11 does not show the same behavior.

Comment: So, do you want to mark this as an answer or there is something else you are still wondering about?

Comment: Done. I'd like other people to chime in to see if they have seen and/or worked around this behavior. According to the link you shared above, Chrome did respect the preload attr in the tests, but mine obviously does not. So either this is a bug in Chrome, or something else fishy is at play here. Thanks.